# Identity Pool creation error on AWS console

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a new identity pool on Amazon Congnito console but its shows an error message when I submit a name

> There was a problem creating your identity pool. Please try again.

I have confirmed that the pool name I am providing is unique and does not already exist.

Is there any pre-work I do need to perform before creating a pool?

Comment: Can you please provide more details like region and the approximate time? Also you can PM me your account number and I can look why were you getting that error.

Answer (score 7):

This problem is resolved. The account I was using to create Identity Pool did not have admin privileges. I was able to successfully create an identity pool after using admin credentials. I know its kind of a silly outcome but AWS console was showing a generic message and I was expecting it to show me authorization issues if there was any problem with my account.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I am using my root amazon account to do this, how can it not have admin priv?

Answer (score 4):

I was seeing the error because of a whitespace in the beginning of AppID in the field.

Comment: Amazon is amazing sometimes!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work around this by removing the custom attributes I had specified. I was then able to add the custom attributes after the user pool was created.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this error while using a federated login on the console. When I logged in under a normal IAM user I was able to create the user pool just fine. Cloudtrail didn't seem to have record of the failed attempts either, adding to the confusion.

Comment: This was the issue for me as well... I normally sign in to the AWS Console using Google SSO. When I signed out and signed back in via Password instead, it worked fine. Why.

Answer (score 1):

We just experienced this same issue. 
Make sure you have this role:

**AmazonCognitoPowerUser**

Comment: It worked for me, but that is a Policy. Or there is also a Role with that name?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had used email as the username but I failed to mark it as a required attribute.  It makes sense... but sort hard to figure out without a specific error message.